# how to make searching queries using sqlite database

Tags: java, android, search, android-sqlite

My question is about how to make searching query with two option. for example search by name and by keyword with sqlite database in android. can i make two tables for name and keyword or just one table?

Comment: Can you Please provide for which tables you want to make queries and what you want to search ?

Comment: You need to check this example : 
https://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/

Comment: in my application i've made two tables.. one tbl_books and the others tbl_title_book and in searching queries i have two option for search.. 1.search by title book and 2.search by keyword

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
Cursor cusror = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_A + " WHERE " + column_1_id + " = " + col_1_value + " AND " + column_2_id + " = " + col_2_value);
```

In your case, one table should be enough with `name` and `keyword` as column. Modify above query as required, like below.

```
column_1_id -> name
column_2_id -> keyword
```

Comment: what is the function of col_1_value??

Answer (score 0):

you can make single table and insert record when you search that time fire sql search query like below ..

```
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + MY_ITEMS_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE name=" + namevalue +", keyword=" +keywordvalue;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```